# Weblogic, maven build doesn't include pageflow folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, pom.xml

Been comparing an EAR file built using weblogic eclispe and using a Maven build.

The Eclispe EAR works fine and the main difference between the two EAR files is that the Maven one does not include the pageflow folder.

This folder contains XML files which have been generated on any java package that contains classes that extend PageFlowController. (the XML file names go something like this struts-config-the-package-folder-structure.xml )

What goals/setup do I need to add to Maven to get it to also do the same.

Comment: What is the project layout ? Where do Toy have your pageflow folder in Your project? You probably need to configure the Maven Resources Plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/

Comment: there is no pageflow folder in the project. Its automatically generated by weblogic when you go to export the EAR using eclispe.
So for example my-application.ear\myapplication.war\WEB-INF\classes\\_pageflow\struts-config-the-package-folder-structure.xml

Comment: Are You using the weblogic plugin? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm

Comment: One more thing - pageflow folder is not a normal folder for a web application, so Maven will not just automatically create it without a plugin for this

Comment: No don't have that plugin. Yes I know its not a normal folder, that plugin may well be what is required.
I know whatever it is would have to be weblogic specific - just wasn't sure what. Oracle doc searching leaves a lot to be desired.